# Object oriented javascript and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

Hello can someone explain me this.

This code has no problem but if you uncomment the requestAnimationFrame, I get Error: Cannot set property 'apple' of undefined

```
var food = function () {
    this.makaroni = 5;
    this.fruits = {
        apple:1, 
        banana:3
    };
}    
food.prototype =  {
    change: function () {
        this.makaroni = 10;
        this.fruits.apple = 5;
        //requestAnimationFrame(this.change);
    }
}
var food1 = new food();
food1.change();
```

What don't I understand here =).
And the problem is only with the apple, makaroni has no problem. I really don't get it =).

Comment: when `this.change` is executed on requestAnimationFrame, `this` isn't what you think it is. Makaroni works because you're setting a property on an object that exists, apple doesn't because you're setting a property on a property that doesn't exist on an object.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(this.change.bind(this));` if you don't do that, you're passing to requestAnimationFrame a function without context (where this is the window)

Comment: finding a dupe for this is difficult, even though it's been asked so many times

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you please answer me this too, why does makaroni exist, but fruits.apple dont? Now I know what I need to do that it will work and why this.change does not work but I still dot get the difference between makaroni and apple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

requestAnimationFrame calls `this.change` with a new context where `this` becomes `window`. You will need to bind the function which you are passing to requestAnimationFrame to the current context.

`requestAnimationFrame(this.change.bind(this));`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use .prototype?

Working example....
http://jsfiddle.net/ebkjvLe0/2/

```
var food = function () {

    var _this = this; //SCOPE

    this.makaroni = 5;
    this.fruits = {apple:1, banana:3};
    this.change = function () {
        _this.makaroni = 10;
        _this.fruits.apple = 5;
        requestAnimationFrame(function(){
            _this.change();
        });
    }
}

// Instantiate a new food, change, alert
var cat = new food();
cat.change();
alert(cat.makaroni);
alert(cat.apple);
```

Comment: @Christoph I'm obviously calling it on an instance of food.